# SQL Update only updating 1 row, when 2 in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I made a form to update sql. I need to update a post to make it featured by sending two values into the database:

"yes" into `featured` and `date("F j, Y, g:i a")` into `date_featured`

It works but only updates the `featured` column, not the `date_featured`

MYSQL looks like this:

featured    varchar(25) latin1_swedish_ci       NULL: No    DEFAULT: no
date_featured   datetime                            NULL: No        DEFAULT: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

And heres my code with the DB details omitted

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'XXX';
$dbuser = 'XXX';
$dbpass = 'XXX';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
$featured = "yes";
$datefeatured = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$sql = "UPDATE pins SET featured = '$featured', date_featured = '$datefeatured' WHERE id ='$pinDetails->id'";

mysql_select_db('XXX');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
echo "Featured on $datefeatured.";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td>Feature
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id">
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Change">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

When I click the submit button it updates and shows the echo but when I check the database only the `featured` column has been updated.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where you're going wrong is using the antiquated `mysql_query` interface. Is there any reason you must be using it? If not, at the very least you should be using PDO which is [not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). I have no idea if you've [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) the values here, and you should be extremely careful with that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your date is in the format date('Y-m-d')

Comment: It was as simple as that + changing the sql column type.